# How can we save the form data from jsp file in database using spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a spring boot API which basically asks the user to create an account.
The account details are showed on a form.
I want to fetch the details from the form and save that to the database(MYSQL).

The model class is as follows:

```
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "Fname")
    private String fName;

    @Column(name = "Lname")
    private String lName;

    @Column(name = "dob")
    private String dob;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "pWord")
    private String pWord;
}
```

The controller class is as follows:

```
public class MController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/successSignUp")
    public String dataToDB(@ModelAttribute("User") User formData, Model model) {

        userRepository.save(new User(formData.getFname(), formData.getLname(), formData.getDob(), formData.getEmail(), formData.getPassword()));    
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "welcomeUser";
    }
```

When i am executing this code, i am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'p_word' in 'field list'
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you think this: 'Unknown column 'p_word' in 'field list'' means?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat, I have a column in the database as `pWord` and that is why i am using the `@Column(name="pWord)` in the **User** class.

Comment: aren't you missing the `@Entity` annotation?

Comment: can you show us your `repository` as well?

Comment: can you please attach DB column as well?@Paplusc Yes, @Entity should also be there.

Comment: @GauravRai1512, It was a copy-paste error, the `@Entity` tag is present above the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to fix this is to put the column names in lowercase or uppercase.

```
@Column(name = "pword")
private String pWord;
```

or

```
@Column(name = "PWORD")
private String pWord;
```

This will avoid that spring convert the name into snakecase.

Name of the columns in MySql are not case sensitive, so it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Paplusc, it turns out i was making the error which i knew was the error. Spring converts the camel case into snake case `pWord` -> `p_word` . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Spring framework changes the camel case to snake case internally.

This is part of Spring Boot Naming Strategies:
We can override these values, but by default, these will:

1. Change camel case to snake case
2. Replace dots with underscores
3. Lower-case table names

Can you try to update column name as pword instead of pWord ?

```
@Column(name = "pword")
private String pWord;
```

it will be considered as p_word if you use 'pWord'. please update column name as 'pword' and try.

example:

```
@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String defaultEmail;
}
And then turn on some SQL debugging in our properties file:


hibernate.show_sql: true
At startup, we'll see the following create statement in our logs:


Hibernate: create table account (id bigint not null, default_email varchar(255))
```